# Hibernate ORM: test only one case/class (Gradle)

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, gradle

I've forked the Hibernate ORM project and I'm creating a test case right now.

I'm using `gradlew test` to run the whole thing, however that takes more than 10 minutes.

**QUESTION**:

How do you run a single test or the tests in that single source file?

The path for my current test is:

`C:\projects\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\test\java\org\hibernate\test\bytecode\enhancement\lazy\HHH_99999\LazyBasicLobFieldsBothUnexpectedlyInitializedTest.java`, where `C:\projects\hibernate-orm` is the project root of the my Hibernate fork/clone.

See

[image]

PS: I found sth here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7459 but I couldn't translate that to anything that would work. Maybe the info is outdated?

---

**EDIT:** Result of Davide's answer:

[image]

The whole thing now took less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test on a specific db, you can run:

```
gradlew setDataBase -Pdb=pgsql
gradlew :hibernate-core:test --tests=LazyBasicLobFieldsBothUnexpectedlyInitializedTest
```

`pgsql` selects PostgreSQL.

Or you can run:

```
gradlew :hibernate-core:test --tests=LazyBasicLobFieldsBothUnexpectedlyInitializedTest -Pdb=pgsql
```

In this example, I'm assuming that you want to test a class in the `hibernate-core` module.
`--tests` is the standard property of the `test` task in gradle and [accept wildcards](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering).

The [Hibernate ORM README.md](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm#testing-and-databases) contains additional details.